# why doesn't the getline() terminate when I input a newline?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
string sentence2;
while(getline(cin, sentence2)){
    // while there are lines coming in
    cout << sentence2 << endl;
}
```

on VSCode, I put my final input as an empty line by pressing "Enter" key. The code returned an empty line. Why doesn't the loop terminate instead?

Comment: Do you want to break out of the `while` loop when you get an empty line, or what?

Comment: yes. according to C++ primer, that's the expected result

Comment: What exactly does C++ Primer say in that regard? It's entirely possible that explanation is correct, but being misinterpreted.

Comment: `getline` returns a reference to the stream you passed to it, and that stream evaluates to false if it is in an error state (in other words, if the last read failed). Reading an empty line is not an error.

Comment: @KelvinNgure Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @chris C++ primer says "After getline sees a newline, even if it is the first character in the input, it stops reading and returns". So I thought that if we put a newline as the input the while loop terminates because the getline returned

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, yeah and it worked. I was also surprised that we can use "not" in C++ like in python

Comment: @KelvinNgure, `getline` returns, which means the code progresses, but the while loop itself doesn't end until its condition evaluates to false. As mentioned in the answer, for streams, that's when a read fails. So `getline` succeeds here and the return value evaluates to true, so the loop continues.

Comment: @chris, that makes a lot of sense since getline is its own function with its own return. The while loop hence needs its own terminating condition too. Thanks to you and Ted Lyngmo for the insight!

Comment: @KelvinNgure Great! Yeah, C++ has a few of these that you can use, like `and` and `or` etc.

Comment: @KelvinNgure  ... and since the answer seems to have helped to solve your problem, would you also mind accepting it?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, done! I didn't even know I could do that

Comment: I suspected that :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition to check that the line is not empty:

```
string sentence2;
while(getline(cin, sentence2) && not sentence2.empty()){
    // while there are lines coming in
    cout << sentence2 << endl;
}
```

`std::getline` returns a reference to `cin` and `cin` will be in a failed state if it wasn't able to read anything - but even an empty line requires a successful read (of `\n`) so that won't set it in a failed state.

Comment: I've been coding C++ for years and I never knew you could use `not` interchangeably with `!` (I knew about iso646.h in C, but didn't realise they are actual keywords in C++).

Comment: And all this time I've been using `&& sentence2.length() != 0`. I like not empty().

Comment: @dreamlax I started using `not` when my eyesight made me starting to miss `!` :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, there's something nice about `not` and `empty` on the same line that make it easy to read.